# define my own entity.tpl for my custom entity?

Tags: entities

How to define my own entity.tpl for my custom entity? I am using entity API to declare my entity and its controller and class. I don't want to use entity.tpl of entityAPI but my own tpl.

Comment: I see you are trying to define a custom entity type. I tried it myself, it was a pain until everything worked the way I intended. So good luck! For some inspiration you can have a look at https://drupal.org/field_collection, https://github.com/donquixote/drupal-nestedbox, https://drupal.org/project/typical_entity_example. Also https://drupal.org/project/entity_operations is something to consider. Either way, you are going to face some research time.

Comment: And for theming, I would generally recommend to work with Display suite instead of custom templates.

Comment: @donquixote I am actually having problem to define my own entity.tpl instead of the one used by EntityAPI .. I don't know where to define it

Comment: my entity's display is something very very specific and very different from default entity.tpl. So, I would have preferred defining my own tpl

Comment: As said, look at the examples. At least one of them (field collection) has a custom template, field-collection-item.tpl.php.

Comment: yup thx! saw it in nestedbox..going to implement it :) one question in nestedbox.. i see nestedbox_core.entity.inc, nestedbox_core.menu.inc, nestedbox_core.theme.inc where you declare the hook_entity_info, hook_entity_theme, hook_menu. I usually separate these hooks also in different files but i include them using e.g. module_load_include('inc', 'myentity', 'myentity.menu'); in my module to load the files... but I don't see any includes for these files in your nestedbox module?

Comment: This is done via hook_module_implements_alter(). But you need to know exactly what you are doing!

Comment: thx! I will stick with module_load_include for now .. hehe 

I managed to get my custom entity.tpl.php to work but I am sure if I need the "template_" hook functions found in the default entity.theme.inc of entityAPI... especially the one for properties... I am not sure if I need them as I don't understand their meaning yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, is not as simple as creating a custom template named `ENTITYNAME.tpl.php`.

You may want to reconsider theming an entity.  Entity-level code should only deal with low-level data manipulation.  Rendering for the browser should handled separately by the Drupal theme layer, not the entity itself.

However, if you want to *override* the theme layer for your entity, you can do it by overriding the page template for your entity (i.e. `page–-ENTITYNAME.tpl.php` (where "ENTITYNAME" is the machine name of your entity).

But this is probably not what you're asking about.  If you insist on theming your entity, there is a solution is written up here: [Theming Custom Entities @ Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/1238606).

To summarize: You do it by means of three functions that you place in the module defining the entity:

- `MODULENAME_menu()` hook.
- Page Callback
- `MODULENAME_theme()` hook.

The MODULENAME_theme() hook is used create this module's Theme Registry entries.

Comment: thx for the reply but will the above method be applied globally? What i mean globally is e.g. i display my entity teasers in a view, will it take my tpl? It does not seem so looking at the code.

Comment: @Gisle Hannemyr I don't think you need any hook_menu() for the theming part. http://drupalcode.org/project/field_collection.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/field_collection.module